# Bootstrap static popover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the bootstrap popover documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) they show on the page the the popover looks like in a static way (before the example where it's connected to the buttons).

I would like to show a popover on my page as an explanation to something on my site - but would like it to always show, without the user having to click anything.

how can I show a static popover like they do? couldn't find an option.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the class `fade` from the HTML? `<div class="popover right">`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you inspect the HTML that Bootstrap use in their examples they've simply removed the `fade` class from the HTML element and then overriden a few of the default styles.

**HTML**

```
<div class="popover-example"> <!-- NEW -->
  <div class="popover top">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Popover top</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
      <p>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popover-example .popover {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UcATexey/2/edit)**

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('your_selector').popover('show');
```

Answer (score 3):

Found a fairly simple solution (not sure if it's the best one - but it gets the job done).

To my popover html I added a class that I called .static-popover:

```
<div class="popover left static-popover" id="testPopover">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Popover left</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <p>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css class:

```
.static-popover { display: block !important; }
```

since the starting location of the popover div it at top:0 and left:0, in my case I've created a css definition for "testPopover" with the appropriate top & left for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of adding the static-popover class. With that in mind, just add a JS function.

```
$('.static-popover').show().css('position','relative');
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach is to programmatically display it on page load. And disable the hide event ('hide.bs.popover') of the popover. Say I've a form (id=myForm) to which I wanted a popover associated. And I want the popover to always show. Assuming you are using jquery, you can do the following:

```
$("#myForm").popover();
$("#myForm").popover("show");

$('#myForm').on('hide.bs.popover', function () { return false;});
```